# laravel doesn't update data until I refresh the set page

Tags: laravel, session

I new in laravel and I'm doing simple edit form that's the code

```
  public function updateSinglePR(points_redemption $pr,Request $request)
 {
  echo $pr->redemotion_mount.'<br>';
  echo $pr->points_mount.'<br>';
  echo $pr->id;
  $pr->update($request->all());
  //return redirect('/setPointtoRedemption');
 }
```

so when I send the new data I goes to the with old values and i tried to stop returning and get the values , and if refreshed the page that update the data it set the data and update it 
I think it's something in the session but i can't know why or how to fix

thanks

Comment: `so when I send the new data I goes to the with old values and i tried to stop returning and get the values , and if refreshed the page that update the data it set the data and update it` - can't understand what this means. Also, what are your routes?

Comment: sorry for that mess
my page was redirecting to ('/setPointtoRedemption'),I stopped that to see what data was sent  and as shown  above I get the old value not the edited and if Irefreshed the page I get the new values that I sent with the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's review your code:

```
  public function updateSinglePR(points_redemption $pr,Request $request)
```

This function will pass to you variables $pr and $request.

$pr is your entity as it is now, without modifications.

$request have your Request object that includes all the information you have provided in your form.

```
  echo $pr->redemotion_mount.'<br>';
```

echo $pr->points_mount.'
';
  echo $pr->id;

This will echo $pr information (not yet updated, of course) to your http response.

```
  $pr->update($request->all());
```

Will finally update your **table** with new data from your form.

If you reload the page it will load a new "$pr" model from the database (now updated).

---

Update for your comment:

Try changing the order of the arguments:

```
public function updateSinglePR(Request $request, points_redemption $pr)
```

Comment: echo $pr->points_mount.'
'; echo $pr->id;
is the new data I enterd from my form to edit,if go to return redirect('/setPointtoRedemption'); the data doesn't update at all